# How do I refresh an old laptop battery?

Tags: battery

I have an old (~8 y) G3 iBook with a dead battery and Apple stopped selling parts for that model. I can't seem to find substitutes online.

I have heard that there is a way to reverse the chemical reactions inside the batteries and give them new life. Is this true and if so, what do I have to look for to find someone who can do this for me? Or is it easy enough to do it myself?

Another option seems to be to open the battery unit and replace the cells inside it. I would rather not do this myself, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this article:

> http://www.engadget.com/2005/06/28/how-to-rebuild-your-laptop-battery/

Comment: Too scary for me. Maybe I can find someone who will do it for me.

Comment: But great article, and apparently the way to do it, if you feel comfortable with the risks.